# Ruby: forward receiver, arguments and block across procs

Tags: ruby, proc

Given code like this:

```
p = proc do |*args, &block|
  p self
  p args
  p block[] if block
end

q = proc do |*args, &block|
  p 'before'
  instance_exec(*args, &p)
end

o = Object.new
o.define_singleton_method(:my_meth, q)
o.my_meth(1, 2) { 3 }
```

How can I completely forward the call from `p` to `q` while keeping `q`'s receiver? Basically I want 3 printed as well, but `instance_exec`, like all ruby methods, can take only one block. Is it possible without changing `p`, so that I can use `p` and `q` interchangeably (the idea is to make `q` sometimes wrap `p`).

Comment: The example would be better if you define the method on an object other than `main`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible defining another singleton method:

```
p = proc do |*args, &block|
  p self
  p args
  p block[] if block
end

q = proc do |*args, &block|
  p 'before'
  define_singleton_method(:pp, p)
  pp(*args, &block)
end

o = Object.new
o.define_singleton_method(:my_meth, q)
o.my_meth(1, 2) { 3 }
```

Output:

```
"before"
#<Object:0x007f5903c2de28>
[1, 2]
3
=> 3
```